# What is the proper procedure to update an intermediate service on Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, systemd

Say I have two packages, `A` and `B`, that offer a service each, `a` and `b`.

`b` depends on `a`. In other words, if service `a` is currently active (running), then I can start and stop `b` no problem. However, if `a` is not active, `b` should not start, at least not without first trying to start `a`. Similarly, if I want to stop `a`, then I expect `b` to be taken down first, then `a`. This all works great with `systemd`.

I applied a fix to package `A`.

What is the proper behavior of the package when I run `dpkg --install A`?

It seems pretty evident that `A` may know nothing of `B`. So, if the `prerm` script of `A` runs:

```
systemctl stop a
```

It will take `b` down along with it.

Then the new version of `A` gets installed and in the `postinst` I restart `a` with:

```
systemctl start a
```

Is that the expected procedure to upgrade a package such as `A`? Will `systemd` somehow always *remember* to restart `b` automatically? What if I had many more dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

In systemd, the `systemctl restart` operation has a special behavior as compared to a pair of stop+start:

- `systemctl restart a` — stop b, stop a, start a, start b (i. e. restarts dependent units, all in correct order)
- `systemctl stop a && systemctl start a` — stop b, stop a, start a (i. e. does **not** remember about the dependent units)

Note that this only happens when b.service has `Requires=a.service`. Wants=, After= and Before= do not enable this special behavior (but `After=a.service` is most likely needed as well to order stops and starts against each other).

So, to make this work, you probably need to run nothing from A's prerm script and `systemctl restart` from A's postrm script if their first argument is `upgrade`, and normal `systemctl stop` + `systemctl start` otherwise. (Note: I may be wrong here ­— not a Debian user/maintainer),

Comment: Hmmm... I have full systemd packages now and the stack works on a reboot. However, if I upgrade A and B depends on A, the upgrade will do `systemctl stop A` in preinst (I think that's preinst) and when the upgrade is done, it calls `systemctl start A`. Which means B does not get restarted. I suppose that means upgrades are just not working at all if you have dependencies?

Comment: Two additional notes that may interest others too: (1) If you do not stop A before upgrading A, the `unpack` process will fail because somehow `systemd` protects the daemon which is not over-writable while running; (2) I use the `dh $@ --with systemd` to build my packages so I am not in control of what function gets called to handle the start / stop of the daemons.